# Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-1.9.3-p551',

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Problem facing when installing rvm install 1.9.3
in ubuntu 12.04

Please help me

Comment: What problem you exactly facing?? Please give some detail information and of course with error message

Comment: when i am fireing command rvm install 2.1.3  i am getting  

Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.1.3',
showing last 15 lines of /home/user/.rvm/log/1428126522_ruby-2.1.3/update_system.log

Comment: Do you run apt-get update before rvm install 2.1.3 ? if not run that command first then try again

Comment: yes i have run apt-get update still i am getting this issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you didn't reboot (or log out) as per the [ubuntu RVM instructions](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm#3-reboot) so your user is not (yet) part of the rvm group, and thus has no write permissions on the logs directory.
You can fix this by logging out, rebooting or opening a new shell using

```
sudo su - $USER
```

That will create a new shell with your user with the correct rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can run following command from terminal and i think it will solve your problem.

N.B: If you don't need rails simply skip command after ruby installation

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties

sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
```

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc

rvm install 2.1.3

rvm use 2.1.3 --default

ruby -v

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs

gem install rails

rails -v

Comment: Thank u for your help... But i have fixed that issue by fireing this command   
rvm autolibs 1

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have issues after running the commands shared on every thread out there, try opening ubuntu or the Linux environment you are working with as an administrator.

1. search for your app (in my case Ubuntu) using the search bar on the bottom-left of your computer's screen.
2. if you don't see the option "open as administrator" on the right side, then right-click over the app's icon and you should see it then.
3. Allow the app to make changes on your computer when prompted and then try the installation commands again.
4. If that didn't work then try the commands shared in this or other posts, but always as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The RVM docs didn't help me. I'm using `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`. Using `rvmsudo rvm install ruby` seems to have solved my problem with permissions.